# Calling javascript class function with setTimeout from click handler set within the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

I want to define a javascript class, instantiate an instance of it in my html page and have the class set a click handler that then uses setTimeout(...) to call a member function of the class.

This is currently not working out for me as I have a hard time understanding the correct way to scope my class and/or calls and usage of the object created. I hope someone might be able to help me out with the example below.

The below code has a few references to $(...) which is jquery, just to clarify for anyone that might read this and not recognize it.

I use the following as a base for a class in my **JavaScript** code:

```
// Taken from http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/create-an-object-oriented-javascript-class-constructor.html
// Base class from which we can derive our own classes with ease
var Class = function (methods) {
    var klass = function () {
        this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    for (var property in methods) {
        klass.prototype[property] = methods[property];
    }

    if (!klass.prototype.initialize) klass.prototype.initialize = function () { };

    return klass;
};
```

I then expand on this with my class in **JavaScript** as well:

```
var myNamespace = myNamespace || {};

myNamespace.myClass = Class({
    somevalue: 100,

    initialize: function(somevalue) {
        this.somevalue = somevalue;

        $("#searchclear").click(function () {
            setTimeout(myFunction,1000); // THIS DOES NOT WORK as the context is now the searchclear html element
            myFunction(); // For completeness, this would not work either for the same reason
        });
    }),

    myFunction: function() {
        alert('we are ok');
    }
});
```

And my **HTML** looks like this:

```
<body>
    ...
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var myInstance = new myNamespace.myClass(123);
        });
    </script>
    <span id='searchclear'>CLICK ME</span>
    ...
</body>
```

The question is, how can I make the two calls to myFunction work from within the click handler which is called when I click on the "searchclear" HTML object?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:?

```
myNamespace.myClass = Class({
    somevalue: 100,

    var self = this;

    initialize: function(somevalue) {
        this.somevalue = somevalue;

        $("#searchclear").click(function () {
            setTimeout(self.myFunction,1000); // THIS DOES NOT WORK as the context is now the searchclear html element
            self.myFunction(); // For completeness, this would not work either for the same reason
        });
    }),

    self.myFunction: function() {
        alert('we are ok');
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried a few things in this direction. The syntax as you write it does not work as such. Using "self: this," makes it syntactically correct but then I'm not able to follow up with the self.myFunction as this has to be done in some other way. You might be pointing in the right direction here, I'll see if I can figure out how the self.myFunction would go and where that leads me.